# passing argument 1 of ‘strncmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast C programing

Tags: c, libc, strncmp

I want to compare some data that the client sends to a server. Bout i have this error when I use strncmp t compare what I read from the socket and the strings I'm using to compare. Can someone tell me why is this error?

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strncmp’ makes
>   pointer from integer without a cast

Server:

```
void
result(int sockfd)
{
    ssize_t     n;
    char        buf[MAXLINE];
    int         temp;
    time_t      ticks;
    int         i;
again:
    while ((n =read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)> 0))
    {
     buf[n] = '\0';
     printf("Message Recieved:%s\n",buf);
     srand (time(NULL));
     temp = rand() % 40+1;
     printf("Ramdom es %i\n",temp);

     if ((strncmp (buf[0],"Axx",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf[0],"axx",1) == 0))
     {
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Option A choosen in %i on %.24s\r\n", temp,ctime(&ticks));
      Writen(sockfd, buf, n);
     }
     if ((strncmp (buf[0],"Bxx",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf[0],"bxx",1) == 0))
     {
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Option B choosen in %i on %.24s\r\n", temp,ctime(&ticks));
      Writen(sockfd, buf, n);
     }
     else
     {
       printf("Incorrect Input");
       Close(sockfd);
       break;
     }  
    }
    if (n < 0 && errno == EINTR)
    goto again;
    else if (n < 0)
        err_sys("read error");
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 listenfd, connfd;
    socklen_t           len;
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr, cliaddr;
    char                buff[MAXLINE];
    /*char                message[MAXLINE];*/
    char                recvline[MAXLINE + 1];

    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);/*----------------------------------------------------*/
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(5678); 

    Bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);
    printf("EDMTS is running on 127.0.0.1, listening on port 5678\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Waiting for incoming connections...Press Ctrl+C to end server\n");

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &len);

        /*Client connects to server*/
        printf("\n");
        printf("Connection from %s, port %d\n",
               Inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, buff, sizeof(buff)),
               ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));

            result(connfd);
                Close(connfd);

    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

**[strncmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncmp.html)** expects a `const char*` as first argument whereas you pass just a char.

Change it to:

```
 if ((strncmp (buf,"Bxx",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf,"bxx",1) == 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

`buf[0]` is a `char`, but `strncmp` expects a `char*`. Instead of

```
strncmp (buf[0],"Axx",1)
```

make it

```
strncmp (buf,"Axx",1)
```

etc.

But, if you pass 1 as the length parameter to `strncmp`, you could also just check

```
if (buf[0] == 'A' || buf[0] == 'a') // resp. 'B', 'b'
```

and avoid the function call.

Comment: Well is not and error exactly, now it does not get into the ifs. It generates the random number and the prompt stays there, if it where waiting for something. It does nothing. Does not get into the ifs

Comment: It does print the received message ans the generated pseudo-random number? And then nothing? Add a few more `printf`s to see where exactly it starts to hang.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass not character (`buf[0]`) but pointer to character (`buf` for example) for comparison.